# Annotation-processor based builder pattern with Java 14 records

Tags: java, java-17, builder-pattern, java-annotations, java-record

At my org we extensively use [`@Value.Immutable` annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/immutables) with `interface`s or `abstract class`es to generate `Immutable` `class`es with `builder`s for our internal data transfer objects (DTOs) [[ref](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/447242)].

We are writing a new service in Java 17 and want to leverage `record`s for DTOs, but we don't want to give up on **builder-pattern** for construction. *We do understand that [immutability provided by `record`s and builder-pattern are two unrelated concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68840772), but for our DTOs use-case builder-pattern is absolutely essential*

A quick [literature survey](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/builder-pattern-for-java-records/) reveals that as of Sep 2023, the available options for getting builder-pattern out of Java `record`s are

1. ***Hand-written* `Builder` `class`** *nested* within Java `record` file

   - manual effort, no *annotation-magic*
2. **Lombok's `@Builder` annotation**

   - Lombok is evil (no offense) and our entire org is moving away from it
3. **[RecordBuilder library](https://github.com/randgalt/record-builder)**

   - I'm sceptical as to how long would it be supported by community
   - plus it also offers several customizations around pure / simple builders that i'm not too keen to adopt & don't want those unnecessary loopholes in my project

---

Are there any other workarounds of getting builder-pattern with Java records? We are even okay to start-off with hand-written nested builder-classes within records (since both options 2 & 3 make us uneasy), provided our [beloved Immutables library](https://immutables.github.io/) starts supporting them in future so that we could seamlessly migrate to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had created an issue [[#1484](https://Support%20for%20Java%2014+%20records)] against [Immutables library](https://github.com/immutables/immutables) for this query and as per their response

- They are planning to add full support for `record`s. Most probably it will be Immutables 3
- Till then Immutables library does in fact offer a workaround by means of [`@Builder.Constructor` annotation](https://immutables.github.io/factory.html)

```
record Uio(
  int x,
  String b,
  boolean z) {

  @Builder.Constructor
  Uio {
    // ...
  }
}

var b = new UioBuilder()
  .x(4)
  .b("xx")
  .z(true)
  .build();
```